# Querying multiple fields in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to search across multiple fields with a wildcard character.

Example document fields:
Boolean type field, isAllowed: true
Text type field, name:John

I want to query all the documents that have isAllowed is set to true and all names start with J.

I have tried combining the two queries but it won’t compare boolean vs text.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter to look for just the is_allowed true and the wildcard in a "must" clause. It will return who is allowed and who starts with "J".

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "is_allowed": {
              "value": true
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "name": {
              "value": "j*"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```